# 404 error on spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using spring security with hibernate, When the user comes at /login and enters his credentials, he is supposed to be forwarded to /users/home . but he is not for the very first time he logins in, he is show a 404 message The requested resource is not available (some times at /favicon.ico if its on a live domain and localhost/ if its on localhost). If he returns back to the login page and logins again with SAME credentials, he is correctly landed to /users/home. why is that? http://pastie.org/8586150

spring security xml:

```
<security:form-login
    login-page="/login"

    authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"

    default-target-url="/users/home"/>

 <security:authentication-manager>
         <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
         </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>
```

-Controller--------

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/home" )
    public String userHome(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        User springUser = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String loginId = springUser.getUsername(); //get logged in username

        result = userService.getUserByLoginId(loginId); 
        Users user = (Users)result.getObject();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("userName", user.getName());
//        model.addAttribute("username", user.getName());

        return "/users/home";       
    }
```

---

```
package web.service.common;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import web.dao.UsersDAO;
import web.dao.impl.jpa.UsersDAOImpl;
import web.entity.Users;


@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    //@Resource
   @Autowired
   private UsersDAO userDAO;

 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
   throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {


  // Declare a null Spring User
  UserDetails springUser = null;


  try {
    System.out.println("the email passed from CustomUserDetailsService in method loadUserByUsername is: " +email);

   Users dbUser = userDAO.getUserByLoginId(email);

   springUser =  new User(
     dbUser.getEmail(),
     dbUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
     true,
     true,
     true,
     true,
     //getAuthorities(dbUser.getAccess()) );
     getAuthorities(2) );

  } catch (Exception e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error in retrieving user");
  }
   System.out.println("debug ---- 4");

  return springUser;
 }

  public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer access) {
   List<GrantedAuthority> authList = (List<GrantedAuthority>) new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);


   authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));


   return authList;
   }

}
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace you're seeing? Please only post relevant code i.e. remove: comments, import statements, sys out, etc.

Comment: just did that, but left out some imports for the reader to see and know about the classes I used. Secondly, theres no error or stacktrace

Comment: What `ViewResolver`s do you have in your context ? Is there a `/user/home.jsp` file in your war ?

Comment: Can you use your browser developer tools (F12) to capture the URL and headers for both requests (for the 404 and the second good one)? Be interesting to compare the two requests side by side.

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM yes I do.

Comment: @WillKeeling the first one was to either / or /favicon.ico  local install and online site respectively.  The second was to /users/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow access to all for the favicon. :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to dosnt getting user from database. Try to return null when u not found any user from database.

```
Users dbUser = userDAO.getUserByLoginId(email);
if(dbUser==null){
    return null;
}
```

I am also sharing tutorial develop by me for Spring security with UserService. It may be help you for further

https://www.mediafire.com/?9e2rd4ozb4qujuj

Comment: Thanks but the pattern as I described is that first it logins in but recirects to 404 but with a back button with SAME USER CREDENTIALS, it logins and lands the user to correct page.

Comment: and it does returns the same user both times (I checked by system outs and debugs)

Answer (score 0):

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/> 
<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
```

solved the problem :)